# org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request...Stream ended unexpectedly

Tags: node.js, spring, http, multipartform-data

SITUATION:

Submitting a multipart form request from Node.js (via node core HTTPS module) to a spring-boot Java API.  The API requires two form-data elements:

"route"
"files"

FULL ERROR:

`Exception processed - Main Exception:
org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: Stream ended unexpectedly`

REQUEST HEADERS:

```
{"Accept":"*/*",
  "cache-control":"no-cache",
  "Content-Type":"multipart/form-data; boundary=2baac014-7974-49dd-ae87-7ce56c36c9e7",
  "Content-Length":7621}
```

FORM-DATA BEING WRITTEN (all written as binary):

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=2baac014-7974-49dd-ae87-7ce56c36c9e7

--2baac014-7974-49dd-ae87-7ce56c36c9e7

Content-Disposition:form-data; name="route"

...our route object

--2baac014-7974-49dd-ae87-7ce56c36c9e7
Content-Disposition:form-data; name="files"; filename="somefile.xlsx"
Content-Type:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

...excel file contents

--2baac014-7974-49dd-ae87-7ce56c36c9e7--
```

NODE CODE:

```
let mdtHttpMultipart = (options, data = reqParam('data'), cb) => {
  const boundaryUuid = getUuid()
    , baseHeaders = {
        'Accept': '*/*',
        'cache-control': 'no-cache'
      }
    , composedHeaders = Object.assign({}, baseHeaders, options.headers)
    ;

  options.path = checkPath(options.path);

  let composedOptions = Object.assign({}, {
    'host': getEdiHost(),
    'path': buildPathFromObject(options.path, options.urlParams),
    'method': options.method || 'GET',
    'headers': composedHeaders,
    'rejectUnauthorized': false
  });


  composedOptions.headers['Content-Type'] = `multipart/form-data; boundary=${boundaryUuid}`;

  let multipartChunks = [];
  let dumbTotal = 0;

  let writePart = (_, encType = 'binary', skip = false) => {
    if (!_) { return; }

    let buf = Buffer.from(_, encType);
    if (!skip) {dumbTotal += Buffer.byteLength(buf, encType);}
    multipartChunks.push(buf);
  };

  writePart(`Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=${boundaryUuid}\r\n\r\n`, 'binary', true)
  writePart(`--${boundaryUuid}\r\n`)
  writePart(`Content-Disposition:form-data; name="route"\r\n`)
  writePart(JSON.stringify(data[0]) + '\r\n')
  writePart(`--${boundaryUuid}\r\n`)
  writePart(`Content-Disposition:form-data; name="files"; filename="${data[1].name}"\r\n`)
  writePart(`Content-Type:${data[1].contentType}\r\n`)
  writePart(data[1].contents + '\r\n')
  writePart(`\r\n--${boundaryUuid}--\r\n`);

  let multipartBuffer = Buffer.concat(multipartChunks);

  composedOptions.headers['Content-Length'] = dumbTotal;
  let request = https.request(composedOptions);

  // on nextTick write multipart to request
  process.nextTick(() => {
    request.write(multipartBuffer, 'binary');
    request.end();
  });

  // handle response
  request.on('response', (httpRequestResponse) => {
    let chunks = []
      , errObject = handleHttpStatusCodes(httpRequestResponse);
    ;

    if (errObject !== null) {
      return cb(errObject, null);
    }

    httpRequestResponse.on('data', (chunk) => { chunks.push(chunk); });
    httpRequestResponse.on('end', () => {
      let responseString = Buffer.concat(chunks).toString()
        ;

      return cb(null, JSON.parse(responseString));
    });

  });

  request.on('error', (err) => cb(err));
};
```

We cannot see any reason for the 500 to be thrown based on the spec.  Tons of tinkering around with the format here but we have yet to achieve the result correctly.

SIDE NOTE:  It works for us using POSTMAN, just can't get it to work using our our own application server (where we actually build the excel file).

Any help would be appreciated even if just ideas to try.

Comment: Probably not the problem, but the first time you call `writePart()` you're adding the Content-Type header which is already added for you when you specify `composedOptions.headers['Content-Type'] = ...`. You also do not need line breaks around the final `--${boundaryUuid}--`.

Comment: Went ahead and made those changes, still same result as expected.

Comment: You sure about the `binary` encoding? That's an alias for `latin1`. See if `base64` encoding everything makes any difference?

Comment: So the reason behind needing binary is due to the excel file contents.  We actually are receiving that file from a seperate micro-service that builds it in memory and posts it to a separate API, where it transmits it as binary.  Doing a single multipart form request with that file (as binary) works for us, but adding the extra JSON form data object ('route' in this case') cases the same server to give us back that 500.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
let mdtHttpMultipart = (options, data = reqParam('data'), cb) => {
  const boundaryUuid = getUuid()
    , baseHeaders = {
        'Accept': '*/*',
        'cache-control': 'no-cache'
      }
    , composedHeaders = Object.assign({}, baseHeaders, options.headers)
    ;

  let file = data[1]
  let xlsx = file.contents

  options.path = checkPath(options.path);

  let composedOptions = Object.assign({}, {
    'host': getEdiHost(),
    'path': buildPathFromObject(options.path, options.urlParams),
    'method': options.method || 'GET',
    'headers': composedHeaders,
    'rejectUnauthorized': false
  });

  let header = Buffer.from(`--${boundaryUuid}
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="route"

    ${JSON.stringify(data[0])})
    --${boundaryUuid}
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename="${file.name}"
    Content-Type: ${file.contentType}

  `.replace(/\r?\n */gm, '\r\n'))
  let footer = Buffer.from(`\r\n--${boundaryUuid}--`)
  let length = header.length + xlsx.length + footer.length
  let body = Buffer.concat([header, xlsx, footer], length)

  composedOptions.headers['Content-Length'] = length;
  composedOptions.headers['Content-Type'] = `multipart/form-data; boundary=${boundaryUuid}`;

  let request = https.request(composedOptions);

  // handle response
  request.on('response', (httpRequestResponse) => {
    let chunks = []
      , errObject = handleHttpStatusCodes(httpRequestResponse);
    ;

    if (errObject !== null) {
      return cb(errObject, null);
    }

    httpRequestResponse.on('data', (chunk) => { chunks.push(chunk); });
    httpRequestResponse.on('end', () => {
      let responseString = Buffer.concat(chunks).toString()
        ;

      return cb(null, JSON.parse(responseString));
    });

  });

  request.on('error', (err) => cb(err));

  // write multipart to request
  request.end(body);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it that you're not calling `request.end()` anywhere?

The (very general) form for sending a request with a body is `https.request(opts).end(body)`.

Also, you could just call `request.write(buf)` every time you want to send data instead of accumulating into one giant buffer (and you shouldn't need to do it on `nextTick`) (EDIT: as OP points out in the comments, this will prevent setting `Content-Length`, so perhaps keep as is)

Comment: I added the request.end() after we write the buf.  We previously had that code writing each part one at a time, we just changed it to try and calculate the content-length before sending the request as we thought that might be the issue but it doesn't appear to be.  Still same error after adding request.end().  I'll modify my code example above.  Thanks though..